# How to find the limit of $a_{n}= \frac{\left [ a \right ]+\left [ 2a \right ]+\dots +\left [ na \right ]}{n^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I have to find the limit of

$$a_{n}= \frac{\left [ a \right ]+\left [ 2a \right ]+\dots +\left [ na \right ]}{n^2}$$

Where $a\in  R$.

I thought that I could solve it by using the Stolz–Cesàro theorem.

So

Let $x_{n}=\left [ a \right ]+\left [ 2a \right ]+\dots +\left [ na \right ]$.

and $z_{n}=n^2$.

From the aforementioned theorem I know that $$\lim\frac{x_{n+1}-x{n}}{z_{n+1}-z_{n}} =\lim\frac{x_{n}}{z_{n}}$$

So, in my example I have:

$$\frac{x_{n+1}-x{n}}{z_{n+1}-z_{n}}   = \frac{\left [ a \right ]+\left [ 2a \right ]+\dots +\left [ (n+1)a \right ] - \left [ a \right ]-\left [ 2a \right ]-\dots -\left [ na \right ]}{(n+1)^2 -n2}$$

$$=\frac{\left[(n+1)a\right]}{(n+1-n)(n+1+n)}= \frac{\left[(n+1)a\right]}{2n+1}$$

And I do not know how to continue from here on. Any help?

Is it safe to assume that the limit of my last equation is $0$ ?

Comment: What do the square brackets mean?

Comment: @GFauxPas the exercise doesn't specify

Comment: must be the integer part of $a$

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$\dfrac{a-1 + 2a-1 + \cdots na - 1}{n^2}\leq a_n \leq \dfrac{a+2a+\cdots + na}{n^2}$$
Hence,
$$\dfrac{n(n+1)/2a-n}{n^2} \leq a_n \leq \dfrac{n(n+1)/2a}{n^2}$$
Now you should be able to finish it off.

Comment: Where do you get the right side of the inequality? Or the left side for that matter

Comment: @GFauxPas $x-1 < \lfloor x \rfloor \leq x$

Comment: Oh, so $[x]$ is $\lfloor x \rfloor$?